# How to change Collection View Cell background color with Pan Gesture

Tags: ios, swift

I've created collection view and added UIView onto it for pan gesture recognition [squared view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAsG8.png)
.
I have an array of indexPaths and compare all cell frames to gestureLocation to change its color.

```
 @objc private func handleTapGesture() {
    let gestureLocation = self.tapGesture.location(in: gestureView)

    for item in self.collectionViewCellIndexPathes {
        if let cell = (collectionView.cellForItem(at: item) as? CollectionViewCell) {

            if ((gestureLocation.x > cell.frame.origin.x && gestureLocation.x < cell.frame.origin.x+20) && (gestureLocation.y > cell.frame.origin.y && gestureLocation.y < cell.frame.origin.y+20)) {

                if cell.isColored {
                    cell.backgroundColor = .red
                    cell.isColored = false

                }
                else {
                    cell.backgroundColor = .black
                    cell.isColored = true
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This code works but cell background color changes several times if gesture location is inside cell's frame. What's the way to change cell background color and don't change it until pan gesture hovers it another time.

Comment: I would have put a transparent button above the view, which is much easier and you can directly handle button click & get indexPath.

Comment: use custom delegate.